# Leetcode question to finding the longest univalue path

Tags: c++, binary-tree

**Question:**

> Given a binary tree, find the length of the longest path where each node in the path has the same value. This path may or may not pass through the root.
>
> The length of path between two nodes is represented by the number of edges between them.

[source](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-univalue-path/)

A solution to this is:

```
class Solution 
{
public:
    int max_len = INT_MIN;
    
    int longestUnivaluePath(TreeNode* root) 
    {
        if(!root)
            return 0;
    
        helper(root, root->val);
        
        return max_len;
    }
    
    int helper(TreeNode* root, int prev_value)
    {
        if(!root)
            return 0;
        
        int left = helper(root->left, root->val);
        int right = helper(root->right, root->val);
        
        max_len = std::max(left + right, max_len); // Why do we do this? I have no idea
        
        if(root->val == prev_value)
            return std::max(left, right) + 1;
        return 0;
    }
};
```

Why do we do this:  `max_len = std::max(left + right, max_len);` This part does not make sense to me. If anyone can actually explain it simply I would greatly appreciate the insight.

Comment: According to that leetcode question, look at example 2 of the binary tree input. You need to count ALL paths that branch EVERYWHERE (not just down). So, if both LEFT and RIGHT children of a node have the same node as the parent node, you need to add BOTH of them to the path length.

Comment: It beats me why they initialized `max_len` with `INT_MIN`... `0` would have done just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The longest path doesn't have to be strictly *descending*, right? For example, the length of the longest univalue path in the following tree is 2:

```
    3
   / \
  3   3
```

In their algorithm,
`left` is the length of the longest *descending* univalue path down the left branch of `node`.
`right` is the length of the longest *descending* univalue path down the right branch of `node`.
Combined, `left + right` is the length of the longest univalue path going *through* the node `node`, which is the new candidate path.

So the line in question actually means
`max_len = std::max(candidate_len, max_len);`
which is a canonical running max algorithm: it processes the candidate values sequentially, one by one, and keeps the maximum value seen thus far in `max_len`. Eventually, `max_len` will end up with the maximum value of all candidates.