# Leetcode question to finding Longest Univalue Path

Tags: c++, tree, runtime-error

Following code is giving wrong output on this input [1,null,1,null,2,2].
Help me in correcting this. and mention where it should be modified.

```
class Solution {
public:
    int result = 0;
    int longestUnivaluePath(TreeNode* root) {
        getLongestUnivaluePath(root);
        return result;
    }
    int getLongestUnivaluePath(TreeNode *root){
        if(!root)
            return 0;
        if(!root->left && !root->right)
            return 0;

        int left = (root->left && root->val == root->left->val) ? 1 : 0;
        left += getLongestUnivaluePath(root->left);

        int right = (root->right && root->val == root->right->val) ? 1 : 0;
        right += getLongestUnivaluePath(root->right);

        if(root->left && root->right && root->val == root->left->val && root->val == root->right->val)
            result = max(result, (left + right));
        else
            result = max(result, max(left, right));

        return max(left, right);
    }
};
```

Comment: Recursion and mutable data is a bad combination.

Comment: Is the longest path in a tree with only a leaf node really zero?

Comment: How is TreeNode class defined? Is this the same question as the one discussed at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57714527/leetcode-question-to-finding-the-longest-univalue-path ?

Comment: Yes, it is the same question @SPM

Comment: @molbdnilo Longest path is determined by number of edges present.